# C++ Storing a rvalue reference through a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, rvalue-reference

I have a method which takes an rvalue-reference. I want to store a pointer/reference to this object so that it stays in memory and I can access it again later.

Specifically, I'm working on a tensor library. The Tensor class overloads the basic operators like +-*/. Currently, if I want to do an operation like `(a + b) * (c + d)` I need to store each temporary result explicitely as in:

```
Tensor temp1 = a + b;
Tensor temp2 = c + d;
Tensor out = temp1 * temp2 ;
```

However, Ideally I would like to be able to chain these operations and work on the rvalue-references directly. However, I need to store a reference to these temporary objects for later use - which is what I am struggling with.

I've tried storing a raw pointer to the temporary object as well as a shared_ptr. However, when I try to access the object it causes a segmentation fault.

Here is a minimal reproduction (toy example) of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Tensor;
class Op{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Tensor> lhs;
    std::shared_ptr<Tensor> rhs;
    Op(std::shared_ptr<Tensor> lhs) : lhs(lhs) {};
    Op(std::shared_ptr<Tensor> lhs, std::shared_ptr<Tensor> rhs) : lhs(lhs) , rhs(rhs) {};
};

class Tensor{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Op> op;
    int data;
    Tensor(int y): data(y) {}
    Tensor(Tensor&& lhs) noexcept 
    : data(std::move(lhs.data))
    , op(std::move(lhs.op)){}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Tensor& x) {
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return os;
}

Tensor operator*(Tensor&& lhs, Tensor&& rhs){
    std::shared_ptr<Tensor> lhs_ = std::make_shared<Tensor>(std::move(lhs));
    std::shared_ptr<Tensor> rhs_ = std::make_shared<Tensor>(std::move(rhs));
    Tensor ret(11);
    // ... do operation here to compute output tensor ...
    // Store references to the parent tensors in the child tensor for later use in backprop
    ret.op = std::make_shared<Op>(lhs_, rhs_);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    Tensor a = Tensor(3) * Tensor(4); 
    
    std::cout << a.data << "\n";

    // Here I get a segmentation fault.
    std::cout << *a.op->lhs << "\n";;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you want to store the original tensors. Can't you just compute the result and not depend on the original operands?

Comment: After guessing what system headers are missing from your [mre], there still seem to be [quite a few typos](https://godbolt.org/z/96ooafY49) in this code.

Comment: Sorry, think I fixed those now. The reason I want to keep a reference to the original tensors is that I need a reference to them later when computing gradients.

Comment: The error I get is because your `<<` is wrong: `main.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Tensor&)':
main.cpp:23:15: warning: infinite recursion detected [-Winfinite-recursion]`